# Cannot read properties of undefined {reading: 'name'}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, react-router, jsx

I built a react app locally on my pc and upon executing `npm run start` in the Terminal it worked just fine. However whenever I push my app to a GitHub repositary and deploy the app, it renders a completely blank screen. I opened the console and found error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading: 'name')`
But as shown in my code snippets below, name is well defined.

Commodities.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Goods from "./Goods";


const Commodities = ({array}) => {
    const {id} = useParams();


    const category = array[id];


    return ( 
        <div id="paragraph">
            <h1 id="heading">{category.name} :</h1>
            <br></br>
            <div>
                {
                category.goods.map((item, i)=>{
                    return (
                        <div key={category.goods[i].id}>
                            <Link to={`${i}`}>
                                <Goods 
                                    name={category.goods[i].name}
                                    price={category.goods[i].price}
                                    photo={category.goods[i].photo}
                                />
                            </Link>
                            <hr></hr>
                            <br></br>
                        </div>                                       
                    );     
                })
                }
            </div>
            
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default Commodities;
```

Home.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ErrorBoundary from "./ErrorBoundary";
import CardList from "./CardList";
import categoriesArray from './categoriesArray.js';
import { Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Commodities from "./Commodities";
import Individual from "./Individual";
import'tachyons';
//import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => {

    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
    
    //const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(()=>{
        return setCategories(categoriesArray);
    }, [])

    if (!categories.length) { // same thing as if (categories.length === 0)
        return (
            <h2 className='tc white'>LOADING...</h2>
        );
    } else {

        return ( 
            <div>
                <Routes>
                    <Route 
                        path='/' 
                        element={
                            <div>
                                <ErrorBoundary>
                                    <CardList array={categories}/>
                                </ErrorBoundary>
                                <button className="grow"><Link to='checkoutpage'>Checkout</Link></button>
                            </div>                            
                    } />
                    <Route path='/:id' element={<Commodities array={categories}/>} />   {/*':/id' here denotes a changeable component*/}
                    <Route path="/:id/:type" element={<Individual array={categories}/>} />
                    {/* for optional paths, use question marks like so => '/:path1?/:path2?' */}
                </Routes>
                

                {/* <button onClick={() => navigate('/checkoutpage')}>Checkout</button> */}
                
            </div>
        );
    }
}
 
export default Home;
```

categoriesArray.js

```
const categoriesArray = [
    {
        id: 0,
        name: "Men's Clothing",
        goods : [
            {
            name: 'Checked blazer',
            price: '$49.99',
            photo: `https://via.placeholder.com/250x280`,
            id: 0
            },
            {
            name: 'Lumber-jack',
            price: '$35.99',
            photo: `https://via.placeholder.com/250x280`,
            id: 1
            },
            {
            name: 'Bucks 19/20 Jersey',
            price: '$65.99',
            photo: `https://via.placeholder.com/250x280`,
            id: 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Men's Foot-wear",
        goods : [
            {
            name: 'Moccasin',
            price: '$24.99',
            photo: `https://via.placeholder.com/250x280`,
            id: 0
            },
            {
            name: 'Nike Slides',
            price: '$17.99',
            photo: `https://via.placeholder.com/250x280`,
            id: 1
            },
            {
            name: 'Nike Air Force 1',
            price: '$24.99',
            photo: `https://via.placeholder.com/250x280`,
            id: 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Give the [CRA docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages) a good read through and see if that helps. `name` is a property in your data, it's not something you are declaring. The error is saying it can't read the `name` property of an undefined object. In other words, `category` is undefined. Are you sure the `id` param is what you expect it to be?

Comment: `const {id} = useParams();` and `category = array[id]`, you need to make sure the `id` you get is a valid index to your array, otherwise `category` will end up being `undefined`

Comment: It seems you are rendering the commodities array on the route that needed the commodities array already rendered so the index could be used to form the URL path.

Comment: `id` is a valid index for my array as shown in the link tag below @PatrickEvans. ```import React from 'react';
import Card from './Card';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const CardList = ({array}) => {

 // if (true) {
 //  throw new Error('An Error Just Occured!!!!')
 // }
 
 return (
  <div className='tc pa2 mr5 ml5 grid'>
   {
    array.map((user, i)=>{
     return (
      <Link key={array[i].id} to={`/${i}`}>
       <Card  
        name={array[i].name} 
       />
      </Link>
     );     
    })
   }

  </div>
  );
}


export default CardList;```

Comment: Also, keep in mind that route parameters are strings, and you are using array indices, which are numbers.

Comment: Yes, `id` is the index of my array elements as shown below @DrewReese :  ```import React from 'react';
import Card from './Card';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const CardList = ({array}) => {

 // if (true) {
 //  throw new Error('An Error Just Occured!!!!')
 // }
 
 return (
  <div className='tc pa2 mr5 ml5 grid'>
   {
    array.map((user, i)=>{
     return (
      <Link key={array[i].id} to={`/${i}`}>
       <Card  
        name={array[i].name} 
       />
      </Link>
     );     
    })
   }

  </div>
  );
}


export default CardList;
```

Comment: How do you get to a route that is rendering a path with a valid index? Please include all relevant code used to reproduce a minimal, complete, and reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Either way, do read through the link in the first post regarding deploying your app to github.